# Docusign | Why is API returning "resource does not support http method 'POST'" | C#

Tags: c#, rest, docusignapi

I am trying to upload a file to springCM and receiving this message:

> "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."

Hitting endpoint:

> ....springcm.com/v201411/folders/{folderGUID}/documents

Which matches their documentation:
[image]

The name is optional, but I've tried passing that in the URL and as a parameter as well.

Here is what I believe to be the relevant code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://....springcm.com/v201411/folders/32dsdfdb-9356-eb11-b875-45df378sdfds/documents");
                
Stream uploadFile = File.OpenRead(filePath + fileName);
HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(uploadFile);
using (client = new HttpClient())
using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    formData.Add(fileStreamContent);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, formData);
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    }
    await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
}
```

What could I be doing wrong here?
TIA!

Comment: are you sure the guid in your URI is correct with the braces "{...}"?

Comment: To be safe, I re-added it.  But same error.  (I removed the actual GUID from the post). TY for the reply.

Comment: Oh, and i was using it without the braces, but just tried again with, and same error.

Comment: The curly braces are not part of the URI, but merely donate a placeholder; and 0000-00-00-0000 is not a valid guid. Also don’t call Result in a task, await it.

Comment: So i'm actually using it like:  /v201411/folders/32dsdfdb-9356-eb11-b875-45df378sdfds/documents   (modified for security) - I updated the post to reflect.

Comment: According to this documentation, URLs should be in the form of `https://[base url]/[version]/[DocuSign Account Id]/[resource identifier]`. It seems like you're missing your DocuSign Account Id

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that as well with the same result.  Even changed the version # to v2.

Comment: After further investigation, I was wrong. Here's the documentation you're looking for I think: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/clm-api/clm101/content-api/

Comment: So is the part before `springcm.com` in the form of `apiupload[datacenter]`? And I assume you have actually created the folder first? If you create the folder, you should be able to get the correct uri for uploading the file by looking at the `CreateDocumentHref` property of the folder creation response

Comment: Dang.  That was it.  There is a different subdomain.  I was using apiuatna11 instead of apiuploaduatna11.  How the heck we supposed to know that lol.  If you submit that as an answer i'll accept it.  Thank you all for your help!

Comment: "How the heck we supposed to know that lol". By reading the documentation ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct subdomain, which should start with `apiupload`. The complete URL should look like this:

```
https://apiupload[datacenter].springcm.com/[api version]/folders/[folder identifier]/documents{?name}
```

More information: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/clm-api/clm101/content-api/